# Что такое "кондачок"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Пока искал цитату из "Ивана Васильевича", нашел другую, которая тоже вызвала у меня вопрос.

*Такие вопросы, дорогой посол, **с кондачка** не решаются. Нам надо посоветоваться с товарищами, зайдите на недельке.*

А что такое "кондачок"? Откуда пошло такое выражение?

Answer (score 6):

В спорах о выражении "делать с кондачка" (о значении "кондачка" и связи его с кондаком) уже сломали немало копий. Но, судя по всему, и будет сломано еще немало.

Поскольку у меня получилось небольшое исследование, процитирую сначала оппонента.

> Происходит от кондак, из др.-русск. кондакъ (Мин. 1097 г.; Хож. игум. Дан.), из греч. κοντάκι(ον) от κόνταξ «гимн, повтор»: κοντός «палочка, жердь», первонач. «пергаментный свиток с текстом песни, намотанный на палочку». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; [Что такое "КОНДАЧОК" | Ответы Mail.Ru](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/54180998)
>   кондачок - шпаргалка, по которой нынче речи толкают, часто ошибаясь при этом.

(andron)

Фаcмер прав, andron - нет.

Кондачок действительно часто возводят к греческому кондаку (*хотя в тюркских есть созвучное слово, обозначающее какую-то охотничью птицу - то ли сокола вообще, то ли какой-то его подвид, оно-то уж точно тут ни при чем*). Признаться, я сам одно время считал очевидной связь кондачка с кондаком. Однако, сейчас есть все основания считать, что это максимум вторичное сближение. Об этом - ниже.

А вот толкование как "шпаргалка" никакой критики не выдерживает. "Кондачок" во фразеологизме по этой версии означает "делать что-то без подготовки, стихийно". Какая еще "шпаргалка"?

Беда еще и в том, что некоторые не слишком авторитетные в научной среде, но весьма распространенные и популярные источники трактуют это слово совсем уж странно - "умело, мастеровито".

> Теперь о происхождении... Сразу сознаюсь, обрадовать мне вас нечем, языковеды считают его очень темным и неясным, хотя версии кое-какие есть. Первое, что напрашивается: нет ли какой-то связи со старым словом "кондак" (краткая церковная песнь, прославляющая Бога, Богородицу и святых)? Нет, полагает Словарь русской фразеологии под редакцией Валерия Мокиенко, такой связи нет.
>
> Пойдем дальше. Было такое диалектное слово "скандачок" (как определяет его В. Даль, это "один из приемов выступки в народной мужской пляске: пяткой землю, носком вверх"). Другое диалектное слово "скандачок" означало "ловкий прыжок в воду через голову". Похоже? Похоже. Но и здесь у лингвистов есть сомнение: ведь если исходный образ выражения связан с такими удалыми приемами, то и переносное значение должно было бы быть "ловко, умело". А здесь - "несерьезно, легкомысленно"...

(Марина Королева)
http://www.rg.ru/2008/09/11/slovo.html

> И С.Максимов, признанный знаток русского быта и языка, в книге «Крылатые слова» пишет о том же: «По этому начальному вступительному приёму уже сразу видать сокола по полёту, который, несомненно, и расшевелит стариковские плечи, и потешит глаза товарищей и молодиц. Он сумеет за скандачком и ударить трепака, то есть пустить дробный топот обиеми ногами с мелким перебором».
>   Убедительно? По-моему, и да, и нет...

(Валентина Пономарева)
http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-17548/

Сразу скажу, что автор материала эту версию совершенно справедливо отвергает.
Там еще много версий, которые тоже отвергаются автором.
Но в конечном счете автор сама тоже сбивается на лежащее на поверхности, но отнюдь не бесспорное гречеcкое "кондак".

> Почти в самом конце каждого из названных Часов располагается кондак. И если первому Часу предшествовала долгая Всенощная, священникам случалось просить для краткости начать чтение его «с кондачка»,
>   (Там же)

То есть автор понимает "кондачок" как маленький, краткий кондак. Объяснение ничем не лучше "шпаргалки", cо значением в современном фразеологизме его ничего не связывает.

В какой-то мере вторит этому и "грамота" устами одного из своих посетителей:

> Дополнение нашего посетителя Дмитрия Виноградова:
>   Здравствуйте! Мне бы хотелось дополнить в рубрике «Справочник по
>   фразеологии» значение выражения «с кондачка». По-моему, оно восходит к лексике, связанной с православным богослужением. Кондак - это небольшая молитва, посвящённая определённому празднику или событию церковного календаря. Помимо основных служб (Литургия, Всенощная), существуют Часы - 1-й, 3-й, 6-й и 9-й. Они содержат три псалма, а также другие молитвословия, что зависит от того, длится ли сейчас пост, а также от других особенностей службы. Кондак, или попросту «кондачок», находится почти в самом конце каждого часа.  Иногда, после долгой Всенощной, когда читается 1-й час, священник просит чтеца для краткости начать «с кондачка», чтобы побыстрее завершить службу и отпустить прихожан. Я сам работал в церкви чтецом, и священники иногда просили прочитать Часы «с кондачка».

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/phrases/?page=2&alpha=%D1

Очень интересно. Но ничего не объясняет. Даже если поверить, что священники используют "уменьшительную" форму для богослужебного термина (что вообще-то им не свойственно), совершенно непонятно, каким образом и в каком значении слово перешло во фразеологизм. 
Тут скорее обратный процесс.

Мне попадалось еще несколько оригинальных материалов на эту тему, но я не буду их излагать, там и версии одна другой "оригинальнее".

Что в итоге?
А ничего. Только то, что убедительных версий нет, а упомянутые выше возможные, но далеко не бесспорные, сформулированы на той же "Грамоте":

> С кондачка (делать что-либо) (прост. неодобр). - 1) делать не подумав, несерьезно, легкомысленно, без понимания дела; 2) устар. (вести себя, обращаться с кем-либо) бесцеремонно. Существует несколько версий возникновения этого фразеологизма:
>    1. Оборот с кондачка - вариант диалектного скандачок - один из приемов выступки в народной мужской пляске: пяткой в землю, а носком вверх.
>    2. Также выражение связывается с диалектизмом скандачок в значении "ловкий прыжок в воду через голову".

(там же)

//=====
Теперь моя версия.
На мой взгляд авторы всех этимологических версий совершенно напрасно проигнорировали изменение значения фразеологизма.
Исходное значение (ну если верить "Грамоте") формулируется как "вести себя бесцеремонно". Именно это значение связывает все или почти все упомянутые предположения. 
Так, "бесцеремонно" это и "прием для вступления" - ну вроде как "прибежал и без церемоний приступил к делу". Это и "грубо, нарушая установленные нормы" - тут понятно. И, наконец, это может означать и пропуск необходимых приготовлений - что в самом выражении, что в установленном церковном чине (распорядке). 
**"Начать с кондачка" - это начать с конца, с того, что должно быть результатом, а не зачином.** Вот оно, реальное церковное наполнение, сближающее "кондак" с "кондачком" и объясняющее смысл фразеологизма.

Разумеется, такая общность совершенно разнородных по происхождению (да и по основному  смыслу) значений не может быть объяснена ничем иным, кроме как вторичным сближением. 
Но тут-то оно вполне реально. Если вкратце, священнослужители, услышав не совсем понятное, созвучное "кондаку" слово, вполне могли даже сознательно интерпретировать его как пренебрежительное название неправильно исполненного, скомканного, "поставленного с ног на голову" чина. А уж прихожане, которые еще не утратили понимания смысла народного или диалектного слова, радостно за это переосмысление ухватиться, оценив за меткость. Ну как не посмеяться над батюшкой, у которого все с "кондачка" делается - т.е. с конца. Причем это подходит и для кондачка плясового (смотрите, там исходная позиция - выступ - неестественна) и для "кувырка через голову". Так что выражение могли подхватить представители совершенно разных поддиалектных и социальных групп.

Comment: @Expert, я по праву автора перенес этот материал на форум "грамоты", поскольку он во многом основан на  их материалах.  
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=5483  
Прошу указать, какую конкретно аттрибуцию я там должен сделать в соответствии с новыми правилами.

Answer (score 1):

По Марине Королёвой

> Было такое диалектное слово "скандачок" (как определяет его В. Даль, это "один из приемов выступки в народной мужской пляске: пяткой землю, носком вверх"). Другое диалектное слово "скандачок" означало "ловкий прыжок в воду через голову". Похоже? Похоже. Но и здесь у лингвистов есть сомнение: ведь если исходный образ выражения связан с такими удалыми приемами, то и переносное значение должно было бы быть "ловко, умело". А здесь - "несерьезно, легкомысленно"...

Смотрите: если имеется в виду что-то удалое, то все логично. Я чаще всего встречал этот оборот в такой форме: "Не решается с кондачка", "С кондачка не ответить". То есть невозможно что-то сделать или решить лихим наскоком.

Answer (score 1):

Напишу одновременно комментарий к ответу *@behemothus*а и свою версию, объясняющую происхождение слова "кондачок".

*@behemothus* выше написал о значении слова "кондак" в тюркских языках, обозначающем какую-то охотничью птицу. Не могу отрицать существование такого слова, но как носительница уйгурского языка могу назвать значение слова "қондақ" (в русской транскрипции "кондак"). В уйгурском "қондақ" означает насест для птиц.

Отсюда получится, что выражение "с кондачка" означает "с насеста". То есть выражение "Такие вопросы с кондачка не решаются" будет иметь насмешливое значение.

Comment: уйг. қондақ «приклад ружья» (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi9w8iuncbcAhUqCMAKHasHBjUQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcyberleninka.ru%2Farticle%2Fn%2Fleksika-kalmytskogo-yazyka-skvoz-prizmu-tyurko-mongolskoy-lingvisticheskoy-obschnosti.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0-nWVKJk20u3LoGzq5LxKu)

Answer (score 0):

Кондачок — это действительно край, конец. Ему родственно слово "кант", означающее оконечную часть чего-либо.  Околицы поселений у славян называются краями, а в Швейцарии и в Поволжье — кантонами.
От основы "кант" происходят также и слова "конец", "кондратий", "кондрашка" (быстрая и внезапная кончина).